# Delete a swap partition without user interaction

Tags: partition, swap

I have a VM with a swap partition on `/dev/sda5`.

The problem is `fdisk` is interactive so I cannot use it to delete a partition without user interaction.

How do I delete the partition in my bootstrap.sh file on creation?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `parted` for example. It has a `-s` flag for use in scripts:

> ```
>    -s, --script
>           never prompts for user intervention
> ```

The command to delete a specific partition would then look like this:

```
parted -s /dev/sda rm /dev/sda5
```

Answer (score 1):

I use fdisk.

If you know what prompts it give you can put the reponses in a file and use that for input to fdisk.

Comment: It doesn't ask questions. It has a menu

Comment: ok prompts, then. /sbin/fdisk doesn't have a menu.